# How to set permissions to other users in Eclipse CHE

Tags: eclipse, ide, self-hosting, eclipse-che

I have a problem with permissions in `eclipse che` because I can't change permissions for other users from `eclipse che` or `keycloack`, so I did change some users permission from `eclipse che swagger API`,
but for example even if user1 has only `read` permission he can delete other users from workspace and configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked Permissions API on the latest Eclipse Che 6.2.0-SNAPSHOT version. And it works fine for me. I think it should work on Eclipse Che 6.1.0 too.

Which version do you use?

Comment: Avoid questions in the answers. Use comments

Comment: Thanks Serhii for your answer, I just updated to 6.1.0 and the problem persists, I can change the permissions from API but even if I remove for example delete actions for a user that user can delete other users anyway,

Comment: @Albert I'd happy to use comment but my reputation doesn't allow me to do it =( I must have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: @karim `delete` action is supposed to protect a workspace from removing. If you want to revoke an ability to edit other users permissions please remove `setPermissions`. More detailed information about actions you can find in [Eclipse Che docs](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/6/che/docs/permissions.html#workspace-permissions)